# What makes atoms move faster if they get external heat energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, gas

What changed around them or inside them? How does this mechanics work?

For **just** example energy is a foggy cloud when atoms are "more defined spheres". So from that point: "spheres" in static 3D "net" positions without movement at same moment energy with movement through this net... Why atoms move and they are "unstable" when this role might do energy fog myself. Maybe because here no any fog and just "overflowing" atomic structure that make them "unstable"? Like weak interaction do job for atomic bomb (unstability of certain elements) or something like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What makes atoms move faster if they get external heat energy?

Heat is energy transfer due to temperature difference. Temperature is a measure of the microscopic average  translational kinetic energy of the atoms and molecules.

Fundamentally, atoms and molecules move faster as a result of heat transfer because microscopic kinetic energy has been transferred to them from other atoms or molecules of an object having greater kinetic energy (higher temperature).

For heat transfer by conduction and convection, the mechanism of the transfer is collisions directly between the atoms of the higher and lower temperature objects. A good visualization of the collision mechanisms can be found here:

http://www.hyperphysics.de/hyperphysics/hbase/thermo/temper2.html#c1

In the case of heat transfer by electromagnetic radiation, the atoms or molecules move faster due to the absorption of electromagnetic radiation. Interaction between the radiation and matter depends on the frequency of the radiation (photon energy). For example, infrared radiation causes an increase in the molecular vibrational kinetic energy. For a good visualization of these interactions, see here:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod3.html#c1

The increase in vibrational kinetic energy is, in turn, is transferred to other atoms and molecules by collisions increasing their translational kinetic energy and thus the temperature of the object. This is also shown in the first link above.

> I cant understand why there is velocity not static transfer: why
> higher energy ≈ higher velocity. Just cant imagine system at whole. Or
> even why transfer exists myself in the space

Assuming by "static transfer" you mean energy transfer that increases the internal potential energy of the atoms/molecules but does not increase the internal kinetic energy (increasing velocities) of the atoms/molecules, yes that can happen.

An example is heat transfer that causes a phase change (solid to liquid, liquid to gas) at constant temperature and pressure. It's called latent heat and it increases the internal potential energy of the atoms/molecules by separating them, without increasing the internal kinetic energy (increasing atom/molecule velocities. In this case higher internal energy does equal higher velocity.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In thermodynamics atoms are treated as point-like objects, whose only energy is the kinetic energy:
$$K = \frac{mv^2}{2},$$
i.e. having higher velocity (being *faster*) literally mean shaving higher energy and vice versa.

How atoms increase their energy depends on how the heat is transferred to the system. For example, if one mixes two gases at different temperatures, the collisions between the gas atoms will lead to energy transfer between them and eventual equilibration of the temperatures.

Comment: "In thermodynamics atoms are treated as point-like objects, whose only energy is the kinetic energy". Unless your only dealing with an ideal gas, you also have potential energy due to intermolecular forces.

Comment: @BobD You are right, but I think that the OP is interested in understanding the basics.

Comment: Thank you. I cant understand **why** there is velocity **not static transfer**: why higher energy ≈ higher velocity. Just cant imagine system at whole. Or even why transfer exists myself in the space

Comment: @Pierre please describe what you mean by “static transfer”

Comment: @BobD as example energy is a foggy cloud when atoms are "more defined spheres". So from that point: "spheres" in static 3D "net" positions without movement at same moment energy with movement through this net... Why atoms move and they are "unstable" when this role might do energy fog myself. Maybe because here no any fog and just "overflowing" atomic structure that make them "unstable"? _Like_ weak interaction do job for atomic bomb (unstability of certain elements) or something like?

Comment: @Pierre I believe you may be thinking of the internal potential energy of the atoms/molecules, i.e., the potential energy at the microscopic level due to intermolecular forces. I will update my answer based on that.

Comment: I dont understand my question myself. I dont understand why atoms not static, why there is velocity. How weak interaction bound and even gluons can "glue" something (maybe because stability of fundamental velocity of just energy in many forms? all is energy with movement at birth?)

Comment: @Pierre think of atom as a planetary systems: electrons rotate around nucleus like planets rotate around the Sun - everything is in motion... but stable.

Comment: @Vadim yeah but from what and why? Planets consist from molecules<atoms<particles<??? . Sun bound planets by graviton-particle (or space curving?) but what makes gravitons and gluons to move not freeze?? What make exchange and dynamical system at scratch possible?

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism of heat transfer depends on whether the transfer is via conduction, convection or radiation and whether it takes place internally in a solid, a liquid, a gas, or at the interface between two different substances.

Broadly speaking, heat transfer can be by emission and absorption of electromagnetic radiation; by transfer of vibrational energy between atoms in a solid lattice; or by transfer of kinetic energy by collisions between atoms in a liquid or gas.

The Wikipedia article on [heat transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer) goes into more detail on each of these mechanisms.